# How to set the marker symbol and marker text in plotly go bullet chart in python?

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I wanted to achieve like this
[image]

I tried the plotly library but did get the expected results.
Any leads would be  appreciated.
Thanks World!!

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
bullet_data = [
    {
        "title": "Revenue",
        # "subtitle": "2023 YTD",
        "ranges": [150, 225, 300],  # Minimum, satisfactory, and maximum values
        "measures": [200],  # Current value
        "markers": [250],  # Target value
    }
]


fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode="gauge",
    gauge={
        "shape": "bullet",
        "axis": {"range": [None, 400]},
        "threshold": {
            "line": {"color": "red", "width": 2},
            "thickness": 0.75,
            "value": 280,  # Threshold value
        },
        "steps": [
            {"range": [0, 150], "color": "gray"},
            {"range": [150, 225], "color": "lightgray"},
            {"range": [225, 300], "color": "gray"},
        ],
    },
    value=200,  # Current value
    delta={"reference": 250, "position": "top"},
    domain={"x": [0.1, 1], "y": [0.2, 0.8]},
    title={"text": "Revenue"},
))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the relative thickness of the main bar and step to get a bullet chart that is closer to the desired one, with the threshold line being wider than the bullet. You can use annotations to add the arrow and text (note that this takes a bit of work because title extends 1/9 of the way into the chart, so the range for the x-axes needs to be adjusted carefully to correctly position the annotation).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
bullet_data = [
    {
        "title": "Revenue",
        # "subtitle": "2023 YTD",
        "ranges": [150, 225, 300],  # Minimum, satisfactory, and maximum values
        "measures": [200],  # Current value
        "markers": [250],  # Target value
    }
]

x_upper_range = bullet_data[0]["ranges"][-1]
current_val = bullet_data[0]["measures"][0]
target_val = bullet_data[0]["markers"][0]

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode="gauge",
    gauge={
        "shape": "bullet",
        "axis": {"range": [0, x_upper_range]},
        "threshold": {
            "line": {"color": "#404040", "width": 4,},
            "thickness": 0.75,
            "value": target_val,  # target value
        },
        "steps": [
            {
                "range": [current_val, x_upper_range], 
                "color": "lightgray", "thickness": 0.5
            },
        ],
        "bar": {'thickness': 0.5, 'color': '#404040'},
    },
    value=200,  # Current value
    delta={"reference": 250, "position": "top"},
    domain={"x": [0.1, 1], "y": [0.2, 0.8]},
    title={"text": "Revenue"}, # title is 1/10 of the entire range
))

x_lower_range = 0 - (1/9)*(x_upper_range - 0)

fig.add_annotation(
    x=target_val, 
    y=0.9,
    ax=0,
    ay=-40,
    text="Target",
    font=dict(size=20),
    xref="x",
    showarrow=True,
    arrowside="end",
    arrowsize=7,
    arrowhead=1
)

fig.update_layout(
    height=400, 
    plot_bgcolor='white',
    xaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
    yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
    xaxis_range=[x_lower_range,x_upper_range], 
    yaxis_range=[0,1]
)

fig.show(config = {'staticPlot': True})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Derek for your response. I am also looking to add a arrow marker with the text written besides it on the threshold mark made on the chart. Thks!!

Comment: @Singh I've added the arrow marker using an annotation